# Updating the image while retaining Annotorious functionality in OpenSeadragon

Tags: openseadragon, seadragon, annotorious

I am working on a project where you can annotate a zone (using Annotorious). Once you have finished annotating and push the "END TASK" button, it will redirect to the next task within the same project. My problem is that after I load the new image, I am no longer able to annotate. Before, I could switch between zoom and annotate mode.

To reset the image, I use the viewer destroy function from Annotorious 2.7.10, but I am concerned that this might affect the functionality of Annotorious and OpenSeadragon. How can I update the image and still be able to annotate?

OPENSEADRAGON CODE

```js
var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
            id: "documentopdftranscribir",
            prefixUrl: "/static/img/openseadragon/",
            tileSources: {
                type: "image",
                url: url
            },
            showRotationControl: true, 
            showFlipControl: false,
            constrainDuringPan: true,
            showNavigator: false, 
        });

        anno = OpenSeadragon.Annotorious(viewer, {
            locale: 'auto',
            crosshair: false,
            drawOnSingleClick: true,
            allowEmpty: true,
            disableEditor: false, 
        });
```

and at the end of the code I got this

```js
if(viewer){
  viewer.destroy();
}
```

Comment: It seems like destroying and re-creating might be a fine solution. Are you encountering any trouble with that?

Comment: Yes, I am. I'm working on this project using PYBOSSA, and every time the task is loaded, the viewer is created. The fact is that if I destroy the viewer, the new image appears, but I'm not able to annotate. However, if I didn't destroy it, the new image loads under the last image.

Comment: Hmm. I don't know enough about Annotorious to be of help here. Have you tried filing an issue on their GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this might be a late answer... but, yes, it's the right approach. You can destroy the viewer to get rid of the annotation layer.

Keep in mind though that after you change the image in OpenSeadragon, you'll need to instantiate a new annotation layer by creating a new Annotorious instance on the viewer. I.e. you need to run this again:

```js
anno = OpenSeadragon.Annotorious(viewer, {
  locale: 'auto',
  crosshair: false,
  drawOnSingleClick: true,
  allowEmpty: true,
  disableEditor: false, 
});
```